# does XSLT transformation triggered by a C# code create any dll files?

Tags: c#, .net, xslt

I have been facing an error when I trigger XSLT from a C# code, It mentions something about dll file access failure every time, so just want to know whether this transformation code creates any dll files (in C:\Windows\temp directory) as such??

(I have mentioned the error and triggering program in my previous question),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dll files are created only if there is an Inline scripting being used .. otherwise (for simple xsl files without inline scripts) it is not required ..

Practically tested and proved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [compiled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx) transforms, I believe a DLL will be created for the XSLT files.

Comment: which is the other version of XslCompiledTransform class where dll won't be created? (.net platform)..

Comment: Please note that I am using inline scripting so the class must support it! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is mean that your system miss some DLLs necessary for XSLT transformation. To ensure use Microsoft's sysinternal utility (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx)  -start it before your app and get error report what DLL can't be loaded.